# My homepage's width has reduced and I can´t fix it

Tags: templates, page-template, homepage

I am creating a site for a friend of mine and I'm having trouble with the width of my homepage.

The homepage is set as a full width page but when you view it it only displays about 60% of the span. Before attempting to do this on my friend's server and domain, I used a domain of myown to show him a model and the model works just fine.

Here is the [homepage](http://bc-plusapp.com/) 
Here is the [model](http://mgaitapp.com/bc/wordpress)

I made another full widh page just to see if it wasn't the template, but that test page is OK (I wanted to show you the link but I'm not allowed)

I thought that maybe a plugin that I'm using (Widgetize pages Light) might be causing the problem, so I deactivated it for a while but the problem persists. Anyway, the same plugin is in use on the test site.

What coul be the problem? Please give me a hand.

Thank you in advance.

Pablo Alvestegui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The widths are the same the problem is that you have this in your `compressed.css` - Line 55:

```
.column {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Whenever you float your column left you lose your max-width as it becomes inline. Fix that fix your website. The homepage content, or all the content is in that column class.

Comment: Your answer looks like is going to solve my problem :D
... except for one thing that I just want to make sure, if you please: In stead of "left" what should I write down?

Comment: Well if you change the "float" it screws up your logo, there's an overlying problem with either your css or your theme that probably needs fixed. If you're unfamiliar with code it's probably best to find a developer so that your theme doesn't get any more messed up than it already is.

Comment: Oh, One more thing Howdy_McGee: Where do I find this "compressed.css"? 

Sorry, but I guess I have a lot to learn!

Comment: @PabloAlvestegui - Not sure, this is not default to WordPress by default to your theme of which I have no idea what it is.

Comment: my theme is called The Morning After. It's a Woo Theme.
The thing is: Why does it work on the test site?

Comment: Do you think if I uninstall the theme and then install it back again it would solve my problem? I know it is not an actual "fix", but could it help?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I have found the fix to my problem. Here are the steps:

Thanks to Howdy_McGee who found where the problem was (see first answer above) I located the cause of all my pains.

1. Opened the compressed.css file with my cpanel file manager and found the line     `.column{float:left;margin:0 10px;padding:0;}`
2. Then I added the following code        `.columnPA{margin:0 10px;padding:0;}`    the PA are just my initials to identify my changes in case something went wrong
3. Saved the file.
4. Then I opened my "template-fullwidth.php" file and looked for        `<?php while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); $count++; ?>`
5. Under this line I added:            `<div class="columnPA">`
6. Saved the file. That's it!

Solved the problem. In fewer words, I created a new style of column in the stylesheet (which I called PA) and then called that style to my full width template.

Now you can [see the results](http://bc-plusapp.com/)

I could not have done it w/o Howdy's enlightment. (y)